# VB pattern with unknown number of digits

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am fairly new at VB and I need to write a function checking whether or not an ID is following the write pattern.

The pattern should be the letters ORG, accompanied by a - and then 1 to an infinite numbers of digits (ORG-1 or ORG-15793131354).
This is my code right now :

```
Sub CheckIdPattern

  If MyFolder.Fields("USERTEXT221").value IsNot Nothing Then

    Dim sId as String = MyFolder.Fields("USERTEXT221").value

    Dim sMatch as Boolean = sId Like("ORG-#*")
    If sMatch = False Then
        Throw new exception("The ID entered is invalid, please use an ID starting with ORG- followed by numbers only")
    End if  

  End if
End sub
```

As you can see I'm currently using "ORG-#*" which at least validate the beginning of the string, but permits to have any other characters at the end, causing bugs later in the program when we go and read these ID.

I also tried using System.Text.RegularExpressions (maybe not correctly though) but it failed because (I think) I can't import it in the program (I only have access to a small portion of the code and the rest is blocked by the software provider).

I know it seems like a pretty basic question so sorry for that and, thanks you very much for any help !

Comment: Please check [this demo](http://ideone.com/ivrZVM). Can you access `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch` method?

Comment: How could a provider possibly block this namespace? Isn't it in the core framework assembly?

Comment: You are right I can access this method and it works perfectly !
So in the end I was just using the wrong one ?
Could you briefly tell me the difference ?

Comment: Well the error I got with System.Text.RegularExpressions  is that it needed to be imported before any declaration. But since I don't have access to the beginning of the code, I couldn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Regex.IsMatch` method using a [*fully qualified name*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s.aspx). Then, this code will do the trick for you:

```
Dim sId as String = "ORG-15793131354"
Dim sMatch as Boolean = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(sId, "^ORG-\d+$")
If sMatch = False Then
    Throw new exception("The ID entered is invalid, please use an ID starting with ORG- followed by numbers only")
End if
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/ivrZVM)

The regex - `"^ORG-\d+$"` - matches `ORG` at the beginning of the string, then `-`, and then 1 or more digits up to the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly !
I tried something similar but now I see it's just the correct way to use the method I was missing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could check each character after your `ORG-` matching, using a for loop:

```
For i = 4 To sid.length
    If Not(sid[i]>'0' And sid[i]<'9') Then
    'throw your exception
    End If
Next
```

Comment: You should consider replacing your test with a call to the [Char.IsDigit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method